можно ли обучить tesseract примерами фото?
Я знаю, что для обучения тессеракта нужно создать файл csv и в него положить нужные слова, он будет искать на изображении.
У меня есть фото счётчиков воды, с которых нужно вычленить только цифры показаний. Тесеракт этого сделать не может, он вместо цифр распознает какие то левые наборы символов которых на фото нет. Если сделать супер качественное фото и даже обработать его убрав темные участки, то все равно не может распознать цифры. Там где между цифрами темнота он принимает это за буквы или цифры или спецсимволы и выдает биллеберду. Я задался вопросом, а можно ли обучить тесеракт показав ему примеры фото именно счётчиков воды и показать примеры цифр на нем? Не знаю понятно ли объясняю.

Что-то я сомневаюсь. Лучше взять какую-то специализированную нейросеть, натренированную чисто цифры распознавать.
